# Do you know online tool for abi encoding?

Tags: abi, contract-verification

Is there easy to use online tool to encode ABI parameters to pass verification on etherscan?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use this tool: https://abi.hashex.org. It can automatically parse constructor parameters from ABI or you can add them manually. After you enter parameter values, ABI-encoded parameters string would be automatically generated, so you just copy and paste it in etherscan.io constructor parameters input.

Comment: Doesn’t works with tuple/struct arguments…

Answer (score 0):

This is coming late,
but to whoever it will help:
https://adibas03.github.io/online-ethereum-abi-encoder-decoder/#/
Disclaimer: This is a tool I designed almost 2 years ago

Comment: Doesn’t works with tuple/struct arguments…

Comment: Not presently, I am open to PRs to add the functionality

Comment: I m stuck on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/112277/ as a result.

Comment: i am also stuck, like @user2284570. we should send pull requests to fix this

Comment: @zfogg but you didn t upvote my question.

Comment: @user2284570 done!

Answer (score 0):

This [Solidity ABI Encoder](https://neptunemutual.com/web3-tools/solidity-abi-encoder-online/) allows for the encoding of data and enables the execution of read and write operations on a smart contract, even if the contract has not yet been verified on Etherscan.

**Step 1: Paste a Contract or Interface ABI**

[image]

**Step 2: Enter the Contract Name**

Enter a contract name so that you can remember it when you use this tool again in the future.

**Step 3 (Optional)**

Enter the contract address if it was already deployed on a blockchain.

**Step 4 (Optional)**

You have the option to either save the settings to your browser's local storage or download them to your computer (to avoid copying and pasting ABIs on a different browser or computer).

**Step 5**

Select a function and enter argument values. Now, copy the result which is your encoded data.

[image]

**Step 6**

In addition, it is possible to perform read and write operations directly through a web3 provider such as Metamask or Coinbase wallet, which is particularly useful for contracts that have not been verified on Etherscan. By entering the correct ABI, it is possible to interact with your smart contracts in the same way as Etherscan.